# How do I elegantly rename Pandas value counts output?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to call `df['item'].value_counts()` and, with minimal manipulation, end up with a dataframe with columns `item` and `count`.

I can do something like this:

```
df['item'].value_counts().reset_index().rename(columns={"item":"count", "index": "item"})
```

... which is fine but I'm like 95% sure there is a cleaner way to do this by passing a variable to `reset_index` or something similar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us try with `groupby`

```
df.groupby('item')['item'].count().reset_index(name='count')
```

Comment: Did not realize that `reset_index` had a `name` parameter!

Answer (score 2):

Using set_axis is very slightly cleaner.

```
df['item'].value_counts().reset_index().set_axis(['item','count'], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

## Using `groupby`, `value_counts`, and `to_frame`

```py
import pandas as pd  # 1.5.1


df = pd.DataFrame({"item": list("aaabbbbbbccc")})

counts = df.groupby("item").value_counts().to_frame("count").reset_index()

print(counts)
```

```
  item  count
0    a      3
1    b      6
2    c      3
```

## using `value_counts` and `to_frame`

```py
counts = df["item"].value_counts().to_frame("count").reset_index(names="item")

print(counts)
```

```
  item  count
0    a      3
1    b      6
2    c      3
```

## References

[`to_frame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_frame.html)

[`df.reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) calls for parameter `names` vs `name` in [`pd.Series.reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.reset_index.html)

Comment: index should be item :-)

Comment: Ah , happy coding ~